# Rails - Missing template users/#<User:0x8334c18>.erb in view path app/views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I'm not sure what I could be doing to get this error.  Obviously, I don't think I should be creating the specific file it mentions in my app\views folder.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you post the code of your controller that is invoked before rendering this view fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your users controller has line, something like this:

```
render :action => @user
```

whereas what you want is:

```
render :action => :new
```

Comment: Yes, I think that was it.  I had ":action => new" and I needed ":action => :new".  The problem was in the controller.